# Is it a good practice to send HTML code from database?

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure that returns the dept. code & name of a department

```
code : P16
department : Operations
```

When this information is recieved in the interface, an HTML card is rendered with the
code & department

[image]

Now I am thinking of sending from the database HTML code as department code
to render an icon on the gray circle.

What I am thinking on sending is

```
code :<i class="fas fa-users"></i>
department : Operations
```

I wouldn't have any problem with receiving the dept. code always & adding the icon
myself in the interface, the application would work well in both cases, but I'm not sure if this would be good practice.

Comment: No .. data is data. Layout is layout. Don't conflate the two.

Comment: Depends on your requirements. For example, if the HTML is meant to be changeable at runtime/configurable by an end user, it makes sense to store it as HTML. If only the text is meant to be changeable then it should be separate. If neither is changeable then I have to wonder why you are storing this in a database to begin with.

Comment: It usually is wise to ask questions like: do I want to have to write a database migration that updates HTML snippets if we decide to change what icon set we use?

Comment: doesn't wordpress store everything in a database?